# Flatten multi dimension array object to one dimensional array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, flatten

i am having trouble to converting multidimensional array something like this and need help to flatten this array object into single dimensional array object.

```
let data = [
  {
    parent_id: 1,
    name: "parent 1",
    child: [
      {
        child_id: 3,
        name: "child 1",
        child: [
          {
            grand_child_id: 5,
            name: "grand child 1",
          },
          {
            grand_child_id: 6,
            name: "grand child 2",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    parent_id: 2,
    name: "parent 2",
    child: [
      {
        child_id: 4,
        name: "child ",
        child: [
          {
            grand_child_id: 7,
            name: "grand child 3",
          },
          {
            grand_child_id: 8,
            name: "grand child 4",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I have try using flatMap() but the result is not what i`m expecting, I'm hoping the result is single dimensional array like this. Its look like i have some trouble on recursively flat map the child and grand child array.

```
let result = [
  {
    parent_id: 1,
    child_id: 3,
    grand_child_id: 5,
  },
  {
    parent_id: 1,
    child_id: 3,
    grand_child_id: 6,
  },
  {
    parent_id: 2,
    child_id: 4,
    grand_child_id: 7,
  },
  {
    parent_id: 2,
    child_id: 4,
    grand_child_id: 8,
  },
];
```

Comment: Are you only expecting 3 levels ? Or there is any chance of more than 3 level ?

Comment: yes im expecting this just got 3 level max

Comment: You can achieve the result with 3 `for` loop, Not an elegant solution but will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only works for 3 levels.

```
  let result = [];

  for(let firstParent of data){
        let { parent_id, child = []} = firstParent;
        for(let secondParent of child){
            let  {child_id, child:grandChilds = [] } = secondParent;
            for(let grandChild of grandChilds){
                let {grand_child_id} = grandChild;
                result.push({
                    parent_id,
                    child_id,
                    grand_child_id
                })
            }
        }       
  }

  console.log(result);
```

Comment: yes, this vanilla version also work, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i finally got some function to solve my problem, i`m using flatMap() lodash to achieve this. thanks :)

```js
function getChild(n) {
    let children = n.child.map((el) => {
        return { child_id: el.child_id, child: el.child };
    })[0];

    return _.map(children.child, function (item) {
        return {
            parent_id: n.parent_id,
            child_id: children.child_id,
            grand_child_id: item.grand_child_id,
        };
    });
}

console.log(_.flatMap(data, getChild));
```